# Easiest way to deploy contracts from Trezor/ Ledger?

Tags: contract-deployment, hardware-wallets

I know about [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org) and that you can connect your hardware wallet with MetaMask, but, as of Nov 2019, I get this error many times:

> creation of Contract errored: Error: TransportError: Failed to sign with Ledger device: U2F DEVICE_INELIGIBLE

Any other option?